# MLE for binomial random variable

Tags: binomial-distribution, maximum-likelihood

You repeatedly toss a weighted coin 100 times. You know that the probability of getting heads, $p,$ is either 0.1 or 0.01 (the probability is the same across all tosses), but you don't know which. What is the decision boundary in terms of the number of times out of 100 that you get heads for the MLE of the parameter $p?$

My friend gave me this problem, but I feel like it's not well defined. Isn't the MLE here just going to be the number of heads divided by $100?$ Or am I missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 1):

You are now told that it is either $0.1$ or $0.01$. Even if you get exactly $50$ head, we know that $0.5$ is not the solution. That is rather than optimizing over $p \in [0,1]$, we should only maximize over $p \in \{0.1, 0.01\}$.

Here is how to approach the solution:

If $p = 0.1$, what is the likelihood that you observe $n$ heads. What about when $p=0.01$? Now compare which likelihood is higher.

Comment: In general, the likelihood that we observe $n$ heads is $\binom{100}{n}p^{n}(1-p)^{100-n}.$ So we're trying to solve $\binom{100}{n} 0.1^n 0.9^{100-n} = \binom{100}{n} 0.01^n 0.99^{100-n},$ which gives us $n \approx 4.$ Is this correct?

Comment: yes, that is the boundary, try to be more specific, what happens if it is $4$? what is your conclusion.

Comment: The conclusion is that at $p= 0.1$ and $0.01,$ the probabilities of getting $4$ heads are equal.

Comment: actually if you compute the probabilities, you will notice that they are different.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's at $n=3.97474$ for which we have $0.1^n 0.9^{100-n} = 0.01^n 0.99^{100-n},$ but this not integral. So how do I interpret this?

Comment: Any $n$ values that are bigger than $3.97474$ would have us conclude that $p=0.1$ is a better estimate. Try work work with inequlities, solve for when does one likelihood is bigger than the other.

Comment: Also what likelihood are we talking about here? Given that $p=0.1,$ what is the probability that we get $4$ heads or given that we get $4$ heads, what is the probability that $p=0.1?$ I've been doing the first one so far, but I'm wondering why we aren't doing the second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128805/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-kid-brains).